# align case with equation above (at a specific position) in align environment

Tags: align, amsmath

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
z&=5 \\
  \begin{cases}
    x & \text{if } x\geq 0,\\
    -x & \text{if } x <0,
  \end{cases}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I want to have the equal sign in $z=5$ to be aligned with the if-statements in the case below.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of "have the equal sign in `$z=5$` to be aligned with the if-statements in the `cases` below.". E.g., should the `=` be placed horizontally centered above the string `\text{if $x\geq 0$,}`? Alternativelty, should the left-hand edges of `z` and `if` be aligned?

Comment: The latter. The character z should be aligned with the i in if, or with the f in if. This is just a MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution aligns the left-hand edges of `z=5` in row 1 and of `if` in rows 2 and 3.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'cases' and 'align' environments
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{if $x\ge0$,} % measure width of "if $x\ge0$," string

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \parbox{\mylen}{$z=5$}\kern\nulldelimiterspace & \\
  \lvert x\rvert=
  \begin{cases}
    \hfill x & \text{if $x\ge0$,}\\
    -x       & \text{if $x < 0$.}
  \end{cases} &
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there no straightforward way (like an & symbol) to achieve your output without having to create a new length? Say in one example I want the left-hand edges of $z$ to be aligned with the '0' in the row below, in another example with the 'x', in another example with the '-',... It is very inconvenient to define a new length for each example.

Comment: @Simon - Short answer: "No". Slightly longer answer: In TeX jargon, the `cases` environment is a math atom (or should that be math molecule?), and TeX has no way of "looking inside" a `cases` environment to check if there's a `&` symbol in there that might be associated, somehow, with another `&` symbol in some other line of the `align` environment.

Comment: I see. And by the & in the first and last line of the align environment, you ensure that the right edge of the parbox is aligned with the end of the cases?

Comment: @Simon - That's correct. Indeed, because the `cases` environment gets terminated by an invisible `\right\}` directive (with width `\nulldelimiterspace`), the `\kern\nulldelimiterspace` directive is needed to assure that the `\parbox` (short for "paragraph box", I suppose) that contains the`$z=5$` particle is placed in the right place.